# Program is crashing after setting the size of a 2d array to more than 1e5

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is super simple:

```
int main(){
   int n; cin >> n; int arr[1000001][3] = {};
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why it's crashing. My computer couldn't find a contiguous block of memory for this thing or what?

Comment: stack space is relatively small

Comment: try using heap memory:

    int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    int* arr = new int[1000001][3];
    ...
    return 0;
    }